# sending a reverse dns request using socket on 53 of localhost or a given dns server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, dns

I am trying to get reverse DNS results of IPV4 addresses. Through dig it is simple by `dig -x 1.2.3.4`. But I have to get same result using sockets on Linux C environment. Ultimately I should be getting start of authority in `recv*` function. I tried by changing IP 1.2.3.4 to `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa` sent this in buffer in socket to DNS server. Very first I did for simple DNS and I am getting proper DNS responses (same as `dig foobar.com`). I think my main trouble is sending `-x` in  `dig -x 1.2.3.4` because `dig foobar.com` kind of thing I am able to do...

Comment: What are you talking about you reversed the ip address?  DNS servers have a protocol, it depends on which DNS server arch you are using.  If you know what the arch is, you can form the correct request by looking at the spec.

Comment: Are you using the `PTR` query type instead of `A` when doing your reverse lookup? That is part of what `dig -x` does.

Comment: @Magn3s1um Thanks ,Yes i reversed the ip address because i saw when i sent dig    -x then questions section get converted to same as i mentioned. Actually i am new to DNS servers and even for this task it should not bother me much.I dont know arch but any how i have to search soa record only, but FYI i am able to get PTR record will move furthur to get other records.

Comment: @ColinDBennett Thanks , your comment really helped me , i was searching A record for 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa whhich is wrong . I tried for PTR it worked thanks again...

Comment: OK, glad you got it working. I'll post it as an answer for easier future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a "reverse" lookup (given an IP address, find the domain name), you need to use the `PTR` query type instead of `A`. That is part of what `dig -x` does.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to send it to a particular nameserver, or just use the normal system name resolving behavior? If it's the latter, the standard interface for this is `getnameinfo`. It's not part of plain C (plain C actually has no concept of networks), but it's standardized in POSIX and also an IETF RFC. If you already have a `struct sockaddr` referring to the address:

```
char buf[256];
getnameinfo(sa, sa_len, buf, sizeof buf, 0, 0, 0);
```

is the basic usage. If you don't yet have the address in `sockaddr` format, use this:

```
struct addrinfo ai;
char buf[256];
getaddrinfo(ip_string, 0, 0, &ai);
getnameinfo(ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen, buf, sizeof buf, 0, 0, 0);
freeaddrinfo(ai);
```

Of course you should also check the return values for errors.

Comment: Thanks @R.. , i have to send it to both . I was not much familiar with those standard interfaces. I read them they are good and will help me . Curruntly i am able to get dns response (PTR,A)from specified nameserver and as well as from local too . and trying to parse it according to my need .. Thanks Again.